# Recursion depth exceeded in Leetcode question

Tags: python, recursion

```
class Solution:
    def orderOfLargestPlusSign(self, n: int, mines: List[List[int]]) -> int:
        mines = {tuple(i) for i in mines}

        @cache
        def helper(r,c):
            if r >= n or r < 0 or c < 0 or c >= n or (r,c) in mines: return 0

            ans = 0
            ans =  1 + min(
            helper(r + 1, c),
            helper(r - 1, c),
            helper(r, c + 1),
            helper(r, c - 1))
            return ans

        max_val = 0 
        
        for i in range(n):
            for j in range(n):
                    max_val = max(max_val,helper(i,j))

        return max_val
```

Can someone please explain why I get max recursion depth exceeded

I tried caching and I have the base case conditions yet its still not working

Comment: How large is `n`? If `n` can take values out to around 1000, you're going to exceed CPython's recursion limits.

Comment: `helper()` called itself, which called itself, which called itself, which called itself ... and eventually it reached the maximum allowable recursion limit.

Comment: https://leetcode.com/problems/largest-plus-sign. Caching doesn't change the deepest recursion level, it just avoids re-visiting nodes you've already visited. You still need to go all the way to the bottom of the stack once.

Comment: n is 500, but won't it eventually stop once it reaches the base conditions?

Comment: If `n` is 500 but you're exploring in arbitrary directions in a snake-like/zig-zagging manner, you can easily go beyond 500. I think `@cache` should prevent you from having an infinite recursion loop by revisiting two cells forever but I haven't verified that yet.

Comment: Look into modifying the recursion depth or decreasing n. I had problems with this before, the first statement in helper will recur exactly n times. I haven't looked at what the recursion limit is right now.

Comment: Side note, think I'd just return the min instead of setting a new var ans to zero and immediately setting it to min and immediately returning, but not important.

Comment: Cache is required because otherwise you have +1 -1 +1 -1... forever

Comment: Wait big no, writing

Answer (score 0):

`helper` can go back and forth between two points without ever terminating as there is no indication of direction. Simple iteration is more appropriate in this case. To avoid exceeding the time limit, we can precompute the longest sequence of 1s from each of the four directions in O(n^2).

```py
class Solution:
    def orderOfLargestPlusSign(self, n: int, mines: List[List[int]]) -> int:
        mines = {(*i,) for i in mines}
        R = range(n)
        left = [[0]*n for _ in R]
        right = [[0]*n for _ in R]
        top = [[0]*n for _ in R]
        bot = [[0]*n for _ in R]
        for a in R:
            s = s2 = 0
            for b in R:
                if (a, b) in mines: s = 0
                else: s += 1
                if (b, a) in mines: s2 = 0
                else: s2 += 1
                top[a][b] = s
                left[b][a] = s2
            s = s2 = 0
            for b in reversed(R):
                if (a, b) in mines: s = 0
                else: s += 1
                if (b, a) in mines: s2 = 0
                else: s2 += 1
                bot[a][b] = s
                right[b][a] = s2
        max_val = 0
        for i in R:
            for j in R:
                max_val = max(max_val, min(top[i][j], bot[i][j], left[i][j], right[i][j]))
        return max_val
```

Comment: Thank you, but how can you know if an iterative solution is more efficient than a recursive one?

Comment: @RuchikaGupta You can run it and see, but almost always, iteration is faster than recursion in Python, all things being equal.

Comment: @RuchikaGupta For one thing, your recursive solution isn't correct as it doesn't expand linearly in the same direction but tries all 4 directions at every point. Otherwise it wouldn't exceed the recursion limit for such a small test case.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Solution:
def orderOfLargestPlusSign(self, n: int, mines: List[List[int]]) -> int:
    mines = {tuple(i) for i in mines}

    @cache
    def helper(r,c):
        if r >= n or r < 0 or c < 0 or c >= n or (r,c) in mines: return 0

        ans = 0
        ans =  1 + min(
        helper(r + 1, c),
        helper(r - 1, c),
        helper(r, c + 1),
        helper(r, c - 1))
        return ans

    max_val = 0 
    
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(n):
                max_val = max(max_val,helper(i,j))

    return max_val
```

Calling helper evaluates helper(i_0+1,j_0), this is the same as helper(i_1,j_0) which itself becomes helper(i_1+1,j_0)... This continues until you have helper(i_n,j_0) which is the same as helper(n,j_0) or helper(n,0). From this deeply nested recursion it proceeds to the next line. That being helper(n-1,0) which evaluates to helper(i_n-1,0) which already has been started but never finished evaluation. You have an infinite loop.

Answer (score -3):

The error "RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded" indicates that your recursive function helper() is calling itself too many times, exceeding the maximum recursion depth allowed by Python. Which is 1000 by default.

You can increase this limit by adding the following code to the top:

```
import sys
#increase the recursion limit to 1500
sys.setrecursionlimit(1500)
```

To add to this, each call to helper gets called 4 times. This has the ability to grow really quickly 4, 16, 64, 256, >1000

Also... Setting a very high recursion limit can lead to stack overflows and crashes, so increase it gradually as needed.

Comment: Never touch `sys.setrecursionlimit`--it's not portable, so you can easily kill the Python interpreter process by messing with this. It just kicks the can a little bit down the road, at best, generally not enough to be able to pass a serious algorithm test case. The solution is to fix the algorithm so it doesn't use linear stack depth.